# MIDI files on Archive.org

Tags: music, download

I'm looking for a large dataset of MIDI files or a machine learning project. Is it possible to filter for a specific file type on [archive.org](https://archive.org/)? In my case MIDI (.mid) files.

Answer (score 3):

The UCI Machine Learning repository has [1](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/FMA%3A+A+Dataset+For+Music+Analysis) and [2](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bach+Choral+Harmony) music datasets for analysis.

Comment: Since this answer is already three years old: Are there any further datasets by now?